# Parsing remote variables in Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

Need helping parsing variable from CSV.

I am trying to create a script, below.  What I am trying to accomplish is resetting a service account's password based on a CSV file, then afterwards I need it to use `Invoke-Command` to edit the registry with the password.  This is for auto-logins.

I can get the script to reset the password, and put a variable in the registry, but it puts the entire line in the directory, not just the password.  I need to figure out how to parse it out to just pass along the password.

The part in question is the code inside the `Invoke-Command` scriptblock.

I was trying this command originally using `$account.password`, but the variable was not being pushed along, someone mentioned the `$using` command, which at least pushed the variable along, but its all of the variables, computer name, accountname, and password.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Resetpassword = Import-Csv "c:\UserList.csv"

foreach ($Account in $Resetpassword) {
    $Account.sAMAccountName
    $Account.Password
    $Account.computer
    Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $Account.sAMAccountName -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Account.Password -AsPlainText -force) -Reset

    Invoke-Command -computername $Account.computer -UseSSL -Scriptblock {
        Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" "Test" -Value "$using:Account.Password" -Type string
    }
}
```

Comment: Using quotes around the variable will cause issues here. Just use `$using:Account.Password` without quotes. PowerShell is trying to stringify the `$Account` object. You can see this behavior if you type `Write-Host $account.password` at your console.

Comment: oh man, you are the freaking man! Quotes fixed it!!!!!  Going on vacation tomorrow, nice to figure out before i leave.

Answer (score 0):

Using quotes around the variable will cause issues here. Just use `$using:Account.Password` without quotes. PowerShell is trying to stringify the $Account object. This issue compounds when you try to access a property of an object because the variable will be expanded and then the `.propertyname` will be concatenated to the the output. You can see this behavior if you type `Write-Host $account.password` at your console.

Update your `Invoke-Command` to the following:

```
Invoke-Command -computername $Account.computer -UseSSL -scriptblock {
   Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" "Test" -Value $using:Account.Password -type string
}
```

Below is an example of the issue:

```
$a = [pscustomobject]@{name = "strings everywhere"}
"$a"
@{name=strings everywhere}

Write-Host "$a.name"
@{name=strings everywhere}.name
```

To get around the symptom, you need to either use the variable syntax (`$a`) or use the subexpression operator (`$()`), which allows variable expansion to happen within the operator before a potential string conversion applies. The same goes for accessing properties on the variable.

```
$a.name
strings everywhere
$($a.name)
strings everywhere
Write-Host "$($a.name)"
strings everywhere
```